# Binocular microscope use, diaphragm?

Tags: microscopy

I am try to review my scope work, since my proffesor asked me to calibrate all the scopes for an intro class in biology, and it has been awhile since I used one. I googled "Binocular microscope use" and saw a [powerpoint](http://slc.umd.umich.edu/slconline/BINOC/binoc.pdf) as my first link.

On page 21 it stated:

> The diaphragm should be opened just enough to allow the objective lens
>   to collect all of the light that comes through the sample. Opening the
>   diaphragm too wide, allows some of the light to escape collection by
>   the objective lens. Closing the diaphragm too much, causes aberrations
>   of the image.

**But if the diaphragm controls the amount of light passed through, why is "light escaping" a bad thing? Why cant I keep the light as wide as possible?**

As an aside, if anyone has any suggestions for review on binoc. compound microscope use, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escaping light causes unnecessary illumination, thus reducing the contrast.
[This webpage](http://rbg-web2.rbge.org.uk/algae/microscopy_image_deficiencies.html) has a couple of photos that demonstrate different microscope setups.